# Try Catch in Perl without external library

Tags: perl, error-handling, try-catch

I'm generating a Perl code from Java code and try to simulate the `try` `catch` mechanism.
I cannot use external libraries. I found two possible methods to simulate this behavior:

First one:

```
eval {
     ...
};
if ($@) {
     errorHandler($@);
}
```

Second:

```
unless(.....){
    // handle the error
}
```

My knowledge in Perl is very little. As I understand, the first solution enables me to execute multiple commands while the second solution enables me to execute only 1 command.
But, I also saw that using eval is not recommended.

What is the "right" way of doing it?

Comment: Why can't you use modules?

Comment: I'm generating a code for many clients and I don't want to force them using an external module.

Comment: eval has two forms; one takes a string of perl code and compiles and runs it, the other (the one you show) runs a block of code and catches exceptions.  it is the former that is not recommended (unless on a trusted string), not the latter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

your second snippet doesn't catch exceptions at all, so it's not an option. Your options in core<sup>[1]</sup> are:

1. ```
    my $rv;
    if (!eval { $rv = f(); 1 } ) {
       warn($@);
    }
   ```
2. ```
    my $rv = eval { f() };
    if ($@) {
       warn($@);
    }
   ```

   Downside (of this second version): Before 5.14, an exception can go unnoticed if an object destructor clobbers `$@`.

Outside of core,

1. [TryCatch](https://metacpan.org/pod/TryCatch)

   ```perl
   use TryCatch;

   try {
      f();
   } catch($e) {
      warn($e);
   }
   ```
2. [Nice::Try](https://metacpan.org/pod/Nice::Try)

   ```perl
   use Nice::Try;

   try {
      f();
   } catch($e) {
      warn($e);
   }
   ```
3. [Try::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Try::Tiny)

   ```perl
   use Try::Tiny;

   my $rv = try {
      f();
   } catch {
      warn($_);
   };
   ```

   Downside (of the Try::Tiny version): The blocks are subs in disguise, so you can't use `return` from within them.

There may be others.

---

1. A stupid requirement. Many useful tools aren't available in core, and modules available in core aren't necessarily the best or even recommended.

Comment: I prefer the `eval { ...; 1; } or do { };` pattern as it keeps the focus on the code rather than the error handling.

Comment: `eval { ...; 1; } or return;`, sure, but `or do { }` is rather worty.

Comment: As an FYI for anyone interested, there is another perl module that behaves exactly like try-catch would in other languages, and it is [Nice::Try](https://metacpan.org/pod/Nice::Try). For full disclosure, I developed that module when TryCatch stopped working due to new version of Devel::Declare

Comment: @Jacques Added.

Answer (score 1):

Eval is the typical approach that we use at work, but [`Try::Tiny`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Try%3a%3aTiny) is a fairly small module and is simple to use. However, since you don't want to use any external modules.

`unless` isn't really a viable option because it won't capture pieces of code that `die` or `croak`. So you are left with `eval`.

```
# named special variables
use English qw(-no_match_vars); 

eval {
  # try
};
if ($EVAL_ERROR) {
  # catch
}
```

Comment: Related perlcritic policy: http://search.cpan.org/dist/Perl-Critic/lib/Perl/Critic/Policy/ErrorHandling/RequireCheckingReturnValueOfEval.pm

Comment: Small module with a lot of dependencies

Answer (score 0):

An update to the answers here: since [perl-v5.34](https://perldoc.perl.org/5.34.0/perldelta#Experimental-Try/Catch-Syntax) there is now a core experimental support for the `try-catch` block, and since 2022-05-28 with version [5.36](https://perldoc.perl.org/5.36.0/perldelta#try/catch-can-now-have-a-finally-block-(experimental)), there is support for the `finally` block. However, there is no support yet for [exception class](https://metacpan.org/pod/Nice::Try#EXCEPTION-CLASS)

So, you can do, without any external modules:

```
use v5.36;
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'try';
try {
    attempt();
    print "Success\n";
}
catch ($e) {
    print "Failure\n";
}
finally {
    print "This happens regardless\n";
}
```